# Extract the first string before comma / Extract all if there's no comma at all

Tags: php

How should I modify the code, in the shortest way, in order to always echo the first string before comma, but if there's no comma at all, then echo the original string?

In the following code, for `$string1` nothing is being echoed:

```
$string1 = "aaaaaaa";
echo '1';
echo substr($string1, 0, strpos($string1, ','));

$string2 = "aaaaaaa, bbbbb";
echo '2';
echo substr($string2, 0, strpos($string2, ','));

echo '3';
$string3 = "aaaaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc";
echo substr($string3, 0, strpos($string3, ','));
```

Comment: `list($newString) = explode(',', $string1); echo $newString;`

Comment: `echo (explode(',', $string))[0];` shortest way that springs to mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will return the entire string if the delimiter isn't found:

> If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, **otherwise an array containing string will be returned.**

So this should work for all cases:

```
echo explode(',', $str)[0];
```

See https://eval.in/947792

Comment: May need to surround the explode with parens?... apparently not, nice one!

Comment: @Dale Don't think so - this should work fine in everything back to PHP 5.4

Comment: thanks, though dreamweaver mark this as syntax error (it does work), anyway to alter the code to get rid of it?

Comment: @rockyraw Sounds like you might need to change the PHP version that Dreamweaver is using to validate the files - it sounds like it might be using a (much) older one. Can't say I've used it for PHP development though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply exploade the string and take first element.

```
$first_element = explode(',', $string)[0];
```